# xslt filter items with less than 100 Google hits

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt

While validating an XML database the following idea came into my mind: I should filter all words with Google. Those words with less than 100 hits would be somehow suspect.

But how can I achieve this using XSLT? I succeded in isolating every single word. But how can I obtain the number of Google hits of each of these words? I have absoletly no idea and https://developers.google.com/ didn't help at all.

(We are talking about some 4000 words. I don't think the Google servers would break down because of 4000 requests.)

Comment: XSLT is an  XML *transformation* language, not a general purpose programming language. There is no practical way to do what you want to do (*with XSLT*). Do it in a general purpose programming language of your choice.

Comment: @Tomalak I've put in an answer that shows that some of what is required can be done in XSLT - not the validation obviously.

Comment: @Lego I'm aware you could use `document()` - smaller problem is that XSLT 1.0 has no URL-encode function, the bigger one is that Google does not actually deliver XML-documents. You could probably make it work *somehow*,  it would still be a waste of time, considering that there are so much better alternatives for web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible to base a *transformation* (not a validation) on this kind of idea, ***if you can find a way to get the number of hits from google in an XML format***. It would just require interesting use of the [`document()` function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256465%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Lets say I have an XML document and wanted to only output certain elements which have more than 1000 google hits. We will assume that we want to restrict based on the `<term>` element in a document, and will start from the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Interesting code starts here: -->

  <xsl:template match="term">
    <!-- you need to find out what this is -->
    <xsl:variable name="google" select="'www.google.com/funkyXMLAPI?search='"/>

    <xsl:variable name="term" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="uri" select="concat($goog,$term)"/>

    <!-- Again, you'll need to findout what the path to the number of hits is -->
    <xsl:variable name="hits" select="document($uri)//path/to/numberOfHits"/>

    <!-- If there are more than 1000 hits, then copy it across -->
    <xsl:if test="$hits &gt; 1000">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Again, this is all predicated on the idea that there exists a Google search API that returns information in a predicatable XML format.**

Comment: It's a pitty that Google doesn't offer such an API. I thought they do. I even hoped there could be a ready to use XSTL 2.0 function getNumberofSearchHits(). But again, I find it really difficult to get the information I need from Google's developpers page.
Does someone know about any other web search engine?